# Python Kivy, making use of isnumeric is not behaving as expected at run time

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error, kivy, isnumeric

Hello I am trying to make textbox in kivy that accepts only certain types of strings. the first textbox works fine and only accepts numbers however cnuminput will accept special characters in the section of the string that is only supposed to be numbers, and I do not know why. Just that it is something that is happening and it causes both the method I made to check for ints and the isnumeric()/isdidgits()/ect to return true for a string like 3$33 when it should return false.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

def ISHOULDNTHAVETODOTHIS(st):
    try:
        int(st)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return False



class CNumInput(TextInput):
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if substring[0:3].isalpha() != True and len(self.text) < 4:
            substring =(substring[0:-1])
        elif substring[0:3].isalpha() == True and len(self.text) > 3 and not ISHOULDNTHAVETODOTHIS(self.text[4:]):  
            substring =( substring[0:-1])
        elif (len(self.text) > 7):
            substring = substring[0:-1]
        substring = substring[0:3].upper() + substring[4:]                  
        return super(CNumInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo=from_undo)

class NumInput(TextInput):
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if ISHOULDNTHAVETODOTHIS(substring) != True:
            substring =( substring[0:-1])
            popup = Popup(Title =)
        elif (len(self.text) > 5):
            substring = substring[0:-1]             
        return super(NumInput, self).insert_text(substring, from_undo=from_undo)



class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        drop = DropDown()
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Student Id'))
        self.username = NumInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        mainbut = Button(text='Lab', size_hint_y=None, height=20)
        mainbut.bind(on_release=drop.open)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Location'))
        self.add_widget(mainbut)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Course Number'))
        labut = Button(text='Lab', size_hint_y=None, height=20)
        clabut = Button(text='ClassRoom', size_hint_y=None, height=20)
        stubut = Button(text='Studio', size_hint_y=None, height=20)
        labut.bind(on_release=lambda labut: drop.select(labut.text))
        clabut.bind(on_release=lambda clabut: drop.select(clabut.text))
        stubut.bind(on_release=lambda stubut: drop.select(stubut.text))
        drop.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbut, "text", x))
        drop.add_widget(labut)
        drop.add_widget(clabut)
        drop.add_widget(stubut)
        self.password = CNumInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: `str.isnumeric()` works. But is missing from your code. You have to post a [mcve], preferably without kivy so everyone can reproduce it. BTW: `isnumeric` and `isdigit` fail on negative numbers whereas int conversion works, so it's not strictly equivalent. Also, if string contains spaces, conversion to int will work, but `isnumeric/isdigit` won't.

Comment: If you know that it is the `isnumeric()/isdidgits()/ect` methods that are incorrect, then in the future, I recommend you only post those relevant code snippets. Make sure your answer is clear and concise to ensure your question gets answered faster.